# Pushover javascript - Sending message issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, pushover

Hey guys im trying to send a push message to my phone using
the pushover libary (pushover.net).

Actually I failed pretty fast in fact Im getting a 400 Bad request error
from jquery AJAX call.

**Here is my code, whats wrong ?**

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:  "https://api.pushover.net/1/messages.json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                "title": title,
                "message": message,
                "token": CONFIG.API,
                "device": CONFIG.DEVICE,
                "user": CONFIG.USER,
            },
            complete: function(data) {
                console.log("push sent!");
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

Error:
**POST https://api.pushover.net/1/messages.json 400 (Bad Request)**

Comment: How can you post to a json file?? Seems odd

Comment: Thats the actual url... Also everybody who created a topic about pushover uses that url

Comment: Your request says its sending JSON but it isn't

Comment: Is there an answer?